# Meaning of [int(x.strip()) for x in f]

Tags: python

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    l = [int(x.strip()) for x in f]

for i, n1 in enumerate(l):
    for j, n2 in enumerate(l[i+1:]):
        if n1 + n2 == 2020:
            part1 = n1 * n2
        for n3 in l[i+j+1:]:
            if n1 + n2 + n3 == 2020:
                part2 = n1 * n2 * n3

print(part1)
print(part2)
```

Here, I didn't quite get the second line x.strip for x in f

Comment: Read about List comprehensions in Python.

Comment: The .strip() method removes trailing spaces, and int() will cast a string as an integer when possible. For example, `int("  12   ".strip())` will return `12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) expressions.

What it does is to read every line from the file handle `f`, stores the line in the variable `x`, strip leading and trailing space off of the line, and convert the (stripped) line to an `int` value.

All those `int` values are collected into a single list, which is assigned to `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Strip Removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string and the resultant is converted to integer type.

For example:

```
string="    123    "
print(int(string.strip()))
##prints 123
```